# Unable to open angular 4 app in a webview

Tags: android, angular, typescript, webview

I am trying to open

`http://admin.aquateams.com`

in android webview but it's showing white screen.

Do I need any polyfill for this ??

Here is webview code for android:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
       webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
       webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
       webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
       webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       webView.loadUrl(String.valueOf("http://admin.aquateams.com")));
```

Comment: put your webview code , so can figure out there is issue or not.

Comment: post link in browser is there a same issue

Comment: try https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel code posted above in question

Comment: @AmitVaghela same link is properly working in browser on both mobile and desktop

Comment: @shahzainali i think we don't need to add an external library for this. https://angular.io is working fine in android webview  .

Comment: if webview is not necessary you can use cromecustomTab in android.
look this link https://segunfamisa.com/posts/chrome-custom-tabs
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel no I need to open it in webview. Eevn angular's website (https://angular.io/) working fine in webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myWebView = page.getViewById("my-web-view");
myWebView.android.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.android.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
myWebView.android.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as to why this code addresses the problem. As it stands I don't know if this is a useful answer or not.

Comment: It worked for me. The site I was loading shifted to Angular...after that I had to add these lines to work.